# Upgrade Fabric and Crashlytics for iOS App

Tags: ios, frameworks, crashlytics, fabric.io

I'm trying to upgrade my installation of Fabric/Crashlytics (we don't use any other kits) to the latest version.

As of today, the latest Crashlytics version is 3.4.1. When our app starts, it displays:

`2015-11-23 16:38:04.413 XXXX[648:60b] [Crashlytics] Version 3.0.10 (56)`

However the Fabric desktop app tells me that we are already using version 3.4.1 for the Crashlytics Kit:

[image: Fabric App showing that the Kit is already at 3.4.1]

We don't use CocoaPods but we have `Fabric.framework` and `Crashlytics.framework` included in the project. Is there a place where we can download them?

Any hint?

Edit:

Here's the output with Debug mode enabled:

```
2015-11-23 17:35:17.612 XXX[26720:2637433] [Crashlytics] Version 3.0.10 (56)
2015-11-23 17:35:17.614 XXX[26720:2637433] [Crashlytics] Running on iOS Simulator (iPad), 9.1.0 (14F1021)
2015-11-23 17:35:17.617 XXX[26720:2637433] [Crashlytics:Crash:Client] Background session uploading supported
2015-11-23 17:35:17.633 XXX[26720:2637933] [Crashlytics:Answers] Answers enabled with settings: {
    "flush_interval_secs" = 300;
    "flush_on_background" = 1;
    "max_byte_size_per_file" = 8000;
    "max_file_count_per_send" = 1;
    "max_pending_send_file_count" = 100;
    "sampling_rate" = 1;
    "track_custom_events" = 1;
    "track_predefined_events" = 1;
    "track_view_controllers" = 0;
    url = "https://e.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/events";
}
2015-11-23 17:35:17.633 XXX[26720:2637433] [Fabric] Initialized with kit versions: {
    "com.twitter.crashlytics.ios" = "3.0.10";
    "io.fabric.sdk.ios" = "1.2.6";
}
```

Comment: Hey - can you turn on debug mode and paste the console output when you run your app?
// Swift
Crashlytics().debugMode = true
Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self()])

// Objective-C
[[Crashlytics sharedInstance] setDebugMode:YES];
[Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class]]]; 


// Objective-C
[[Crashlytics sharedInstance] setDebugMode:YES];
[Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class]]];

Comment: I've just added the output in the original question :)

Comment: Hmm can you double check that you have this app selected in Fabric.app and not another app?

Comment: I double checked when I posted (and rechecked again), it is the right app selected in Fabric.app =/

Comment: I've got it working. I've "Archive" the project as if I was sending a build to testers. I now have the "Update" button right next to "Crashlytics 3.4.1" in the Fabric.app

Comment: Hmm interesting. Thanks for sharing this! If you hit the problem again, definitely shoot us an email to support@fabric.io and we can dig into it.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. After clicking on "Update", Fabric.app asked me to rebuild the project (cmd-b). I did it but nothing happened and Fabric.app shows a spinner indefinitely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem as you. My project was using an old version of the frameworks, yet the "smart" `Fabric.app` was infuriatingly sure that I had the latest version.

Since there's no convenient download-link-for-grownups, you have to get the Fabric/Crashlytics frameworks like so:

1. quit the `Fabric.app`
2. remove its cache: `rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.mac`
3. run the `Fabric.app` and wait for it to populate the above directory
4. then either
    a. simply do the integration yourself, using the contents of
   `~/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.mac/5b91b14e832a7b1c29441ec5ba109810/sdks/ios/com.twitter.crashlytics.ios-default.zip`
   and `~/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.mac/5b91b14e832a7b1c29441ec5ba109810/sdks/ios/io.fabric.sdk.ios-default.zip`, or
    b. try your luck once again, letting the app integrate the frameworks into your project

Thanks to [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1257838/alexizamerican) for helping me with this Fabric.app workaround.

Comment: It works like a charm. Yep, many thanks Alex (who has just sent me the same solution by email) for the support, it's greatly appreciated :)

Comment: We've changed the target name since we've included the Fabric SDK, it might be related to the hiccups in Fabric.app...

Comment: Glad you're both all set :)